# Map Grid Index / Reference for Canadian Topo Map

Tags: kml, canada, kmz, topography

Does anyone know where I can find some KML at different resolutions to show the grid reference for the Canadian topographic maps (CanTopo and toporama). Much like is displayed on the map here: http://wms.ess-ws.nrcan.gc.ca/wms/indexcouverture_cantopo

As you zoom in the grids get more detailed so I imagine I'd require multiple KML files to provide the different levels of detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those look like the grids for the National Topographic System in Canada.

They can be downloaded from [Geogratis](http://geogratis.cgdi.gc.ca/) as the [Vector Indexes of the National Topographic System of Canada](ftp://ftp.geogratis.gc.ca/pub/nrcan_rncan/vector/index).

They are available as [kmz](ftp://ftp.geogratis.gc.ca/pub/nrcan_rncan/vector/index/nts_snrc.kmz) or [shp](http://ftp2.cits.rncan.gc.ca/pub/index/nts_snrc.zip).

They can be converted to KML with [ogr2ogr](http://gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) from [gdal](http://gdal.org/).

Comment: Thanks SaultDon - that was EXACTLY! what I was after. Much appreciated :)

Comment: The link to the Vector Indexes of the National Topographic System of Canada has been changed to: ftp.geogratis.gc.ca/pub/nrcan_rncan/vector/index