# Displaying rectified raster (topos) in Google Earth

Tags: google-earth, topography

Looking for tool or an easy way (limited programming skills here) to display geotiffs in Google Earth. Specifically Canadian topos [like this](http://geogratis.gc.ca/api/en/nrcan-rncan/ess-sst/c9a48931-19a4-4500-88bf-89f3533a20dd.html)

This Geogratis site has the same topos in regular tif and pdf formats but can't seem to locate a way to display them in Google Earth. I found [this script](https://github.com/grothered/tif2kml) but don't know how to implement it.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: the script uses gdal2tiles from here http://www.klokan.cz/projects/gdal2tiles/

Comment: thanks for all the help... which is easier for non-programmer to implement, gdal2tiles or maptiler? The wms is nice but I think I need something more customizable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to have any programming skills to do this.
The data is available in geographic coordinates, take that file and use [maptiler](http://www.maptiler.org/) to convert the file to a KMLSUPEROVERLAY.

You can do this with qgis too, but maptiler is probably a bit easier.

Comment: Maptiler did the job i was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This **Network KML** is already providing the Topos to view

http://www.gelib.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/natural-resources-canada-toporama_nl.kml

You can have all layers on - or select individual layers.

Use the Opacity Slider by right clicking the layer and can be adjusted based on your preference of transparency.

Comment: Indexes of these files  can be also be shown see - http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14736/map-grid-index-reference-for-canadian-topo-map